# Unable to compile transitive dependency of aar from android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There are some questions regarding transitive dependencies in gradle but none of them solved my problem.

I took following steps:

1. Created a new Android Studio project: **A**.
2. Created a new "Android Library" module: **B** in that project.
3. Added a dependency in build.gradle of module B as:

   ```
   compile ('com.abc:sdk:0.8.0@aar')
   ```
4. Added a dependency in app level build.gradle as:

   ```
   compile project(":B")
   ```

   After this step Android Studio automatically generated an AAR file for **B**.
5. Created another Android Studio project: B and imported this AAR file as a module in this project.

   Everything is working fine in project A. But I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` when I try to run project B.

Explicitly adding the dependency of **abc:sdk** in project B solves the problem but my purpose is to compile abc:sdk without explicitly adding dependency to project B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aar file **doesn't contain** the transitive dependencies.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file, you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

Using a maven repository, you will not have the same issue.
Gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file.

Comment: Is there any other way that will serve my purpose if I do not want to upload it to maven?

Comment: No for my knowledge . but you can use a private maven.

Comment: So will gradle download and compile transitive dependency automatically or I will have to specify that somehow?